# how to tell sphinx that source code is in this path and build in that path

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to run sphinx on a library in a conda virtual environment with path

```
/anaconda/envs/test_env/lib/site-packages/mypackage
```

and put the html files in the path

```
/myhtmlfiles/myproject
```

where my `conf.py` and `*.rst` files are in the path

```
/sphinx/myproject
```

---

***question***
What are the `conf.py` settings I need to edit to make this happen when I run

```
make html
```

Answer (score 1):

`make` is not a sphinx command. That command actually runs either a `make` with a Makefile or `make.bat` (depending on your operating system), which then locates the relevant files before invoking `sphinx-build`. You will need to modify the make files and/or set the proper environmental variables.

Answer (score 1):

The output directory is not a conf.py setting. It is an argument (`builddir`) to [sphinx-build](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-build). Set it in the Makefile.

You tell Sphinx where the package is by [updating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc) [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) in conf.py.

Comment: Note that if you want to put `conf.py` in a different directory to your source content RST etc, use the `sphinx-build` `-c` option to specify the directory containing `conf.py`, as in `-c .`. Note also that `master_doc` setting in `conf.py` is relative to the output directory, not the conf.py directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the Makefile, as others mentioned. I normally just use the `sphinx-build` command.

`$ sphinx-build [options] sourcedir outputdir`
(html is the default build option; you can specify it using `-b html`)

The location of the package only matters if you're auto-generating api docs. If you're running the command to build from /sphinx/myproject, you'd use:

`$ sphinx-build ./ /myhtmlfiles/myproject`

This places the build output in a sub-directory, `/sphinx/myproject/myhtmlfiles/myproject`. If the build location isn't a subdirectory of `sphinx/myproject`, be sure to specify the correct path.

If you want to auto-generate api docs, you'll want to use [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-apidoc):

`$ sphinx-apidoc [options] -o outputdir packagedir [pathnames]`

Answer (score 1):

To change the output directory you have `Makefile` so you do not have to do this through `conf.py`

Looks like you have `html` target in the `Makefile`:

If it looks something like this:

```
html:
    $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html
```

Then you can just change the variables:

```
SPHINXOPTS    =
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
BUILDDIR      = ../../build/main

ALLSPHINXOPTS   = -d $(BUILDDIR)/doctrees $(SPHINXOPTS) ./
```

While this takes the source from current directory, to use different directory:

```
ALLSPHINXOPTS   = -d $(BUILDDIR)/doctrees $(SPHINXOPTS) ./mySourceFolder
```

If you run `sphinx-build` on command line you can do these things without make, see the `sphinx-build -h`:

```
% sphinx-build -h
usage: sphinx-build [OPTIONS] SOURCEDIR OUTPUTDIR [FILENAMES...]

Generate documentation from source files. sphinx-build generates documentation
from the files in SOURCEDIR and places it in OUTPUTDIR. It looks for 'conf.py'
in SOURCEDIR for the configuration settings. The 'sphinx-quickstart' tool may
be used to generate template files, including 'conf.py' sphinx-build can
create documentation in different formats. A format is selected by specifying
the builder name on the command line; it defaults to HTML. Builders can also
perform other tasks related to documentation processing. By default,
everything that is outdated is built. Output only for selected files can be
built by specifying individual filenames.

positional arguments:
  sourcedir         path to documentation source files
  outputdir         path to output directory
  filenames         a list of specific files to rebuild. Ignored if -a is
                    specified

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --version         show program's version number and exit

general options:
  -b BUILDER        builder to use (default: html)
  -a                write all files (default: only write new and changed
                    files)
  -E                don't use a saved environment, always read all files
  -d PATH           path for the cached environment and doctree files
                    (default: OUTPUTDIR/.doctrees)
  -j N              build in parallel with N processes where possible (special
                    value "auto" will set N to cpu-count)

build configuration options:
  -c PATH           path where configuration file (conf.py) is located
                    (default: same as SOURCEDIR)
  -C                use no config file at all, only -D options
  -D setting=value  override a setting in configuration file
  -A name=value     pass a value into HTML templates
  -t TAG            define tag: include "only" blocks with TAG
  -n                nit-picky mode, warn about all missing references

console output options:
  -v                increase verbosity (can be repeated)
  -q                no output on stdout, just warnings on stderr
  -Q                no output at all, not even warnings
  --color           do emit colored output (default: auto-detect)
  -N, --no-color    do not emit colored output (default: auto-detect)
  -w FILE           write warnings (and errors) to given file
  -W                turn warnings into errors
  --keep-going      with -W, keep going when getting warnings
  -T                show full traceback on exception
  -P                run Pdb on exception

For more information, visit <http://sphinx-doc.org/>.
```

usage: sphinx-build [OPTIONS] **SOURCEDIR** *OUTPUTDIR* [FILENAMES...]

The first argument is your **source** and the second is your *output* directory.
You can't change source directory from conf.py as that is in your source directory, it's like knowing your source directory before deciding what the source directory is. When you point sphinx to a conf.py then it's already decided what the source directory is.

Comment: If you want have conf.py in different directory than is rest of your source, then maybe symlinks could work?

Answer (score 0):

Place a python file with this content into the `source` folder of sphinx

```
import os
from subprocess import call

# path to source
this_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
packagedir = os.path.join(this_path, '..','some folder', 'some other folder')  # this is the path to your source!
outputdir = os.path.join(this_path)

# Command you should run
# sphinx-apidoc [options] -o outputdir packagedir [pathnames]

call(["sphinx-apidoc", "-o", outputdir, packagedir])
call([os.path.join('..', 'make.bat'), 'html'])
call([os.path.join('..', 'make.bat'), 'latex'])
```

Enjoy